# LightDM not Behaving as Expexted

Tags: unity, gnome, login, lightdm, login-screen

I seem to be having some odd lightdm behavioral issues. So far this what I have in my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file:

```
user-session=gnome-classic
greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-show-manual-login=true
allow-guest=false
greeter-hide-users=true
```

How I'd expect lightdm to behave based on the above is the means to type in a username, list of available users hidden and the guest account not available.  However all I get is as follows:

[image]

I've read on these forums and elsewhere that unless `greeter-session` is set to `lightdm-gtk-greeter` the options in my lightdm.conf file will not be honored.

However, if I make the changes accordingly then reboot, all I see is as follows:

[image]

I'm running 12.04.2 within a VM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dan.

Comment: UPDATE:  I didn't realize that lightdm-gtk-greeter was a package.  Once I installed the it, I was able to avoid the low-graphics issue, however, there's been a misunderstanding on my part.  I also didn't realize that by specifying lightdm-gtk-greeter it would display the old gnome greeter.  I want the unity greeter.  For clarity, even with the gnome greeter, i was still unable to enter usernames etc.  Seems no matter what i do, i get the same un-desired affect with both the gnome and unity greeters.

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE:  I'm going through the process of elimination in an attempt to resolve this but now I'm even more confused than ever.  I set greeter-hide-users=false so I was expecting to see some users within the greeter and although that was the case, I can now also see Login option!  If I select Login, it immediately asks for a password (no username option).  Totally confused!!!  Can anyone confirm whether this behavior associated to a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved!!!!!!

Transpired that the issue was nothing to do with lightdm.  An application had been installed that made some custom changes to the /etc/pam.d/lightdm and /etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin files.  I restored them to their defaults and the issue was resolved.  I'm now seeing exactly what I was expecting.  I hope I've not upset the application in question too much by doing do:-)!!

Thanks to those who bothered to take the time to read this post!